# Applying pseudo class "before" and "after" to multi-line text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a pseudo before and after vertical line to a textfield for styling purposes. These elements need to be flush to the text -20px left and -20px right.

This works fine when the text is on one line as an inline-block, but as soon as the text spans multiple lines the width expands to that of the parent and the pseudo elements are no longer just 20px from the text.

Is there a way in which I can accomplish this using CSS?

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

h2::before,
h2::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}

h2::before {
  left: -20px;
}

h2::after {
  right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!--  Single line example works as the black bars are 20px away from the start/end of text-->
<div class="container">
  <h2><span>This is a title</span></h2>
</div>

<br> <br>

<!--  double line doesn't work because the h2 is now the full width of the container -->
<div class="container">
  <h2><span>This is loooonnggggggggggggggggggggggeeeeerrr</span></h2>
</div>
```

Edit: Here is a working version using tables, but if anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqveLQ

Comment: Did you try `height: 100%;` on `h2:before` and `h2:after`?

Comment: Can you use justified text, like use whitespace in the `<h2>` to fill up remaining space?

Comment: @JBDouble05 nope

Comment: @Ryan, why not?

Comment: Perhaps adding an image of what you're trying would help

Comment: @JBDouble05 we have design requirements so we're unable to justify text

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - we have a working version using tables in the following pen, but any other suggestions welcome: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqveLQ

Comment: @Ryan I still don't get it. So the codepen is exactly the right visual output?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The StackOverflow snippet is wrong because on the double line example the black vertical lines are not 20px away from the text like they are on the single line example. The codepen is correct because the vertical lines are 20px away from the text.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved your code to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2Lr6xy5/13/ and removed `position: absolute` along with stripping out some of the other styles as they seemed unnecessary and I think I have created what you're after.

Here is the **updated** CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 40px;
}


h2{
  display: inline-block;
}

h2:after,
h2:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Neelam, thanks for taking a look but this isn't what I'm trying to do.

If you look at my original example you will see the single line is correct because my vertical bars are 20px away from the text.
The multi-line example is incorrect because the vertical bars are now 20px away from the text

Answer (score 0):

So from what i can see is the issue here is where you are applying the borders with before and after. You need to alter where you apply your borders. Remove them from the h2, and add in a new html element that wraps the h2 and apply there.

eg:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="headerwrap">
         <h2><span>This is loooonnggggggggggggggggggggggeeeeerrr</span></h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="headerwrap">
        <h2><span>This is a title</span></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .headerwrap::before,
    .headerwrap::after {
       content: '';
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       bottom:0;
       margin:auto;
       width: 4px;
       height: 20px;
       background: black;
     }

     .headerwrap::before {
       left: 10px;
      }

      .headerwrap::after {
        right: 10px;
      }
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/VGbJjO?editors=1100#0

Edit: altered example after comments - https://codepen.io/FEARtheMoose/pen/VGbJjO

Comment: Hi Moose, thanks for taking a look at it!


Unfortunately that isn't what I'm after (I realise my original post might not make sense, I'm finding it hard to explain! Im wanting the vertical bars to always be 20px from the left and right of the text, in your codepen the bars remain in the same position no matter the left of the text.

Comment: No worries. Although did you ever consider just splitting the text up into more elements to get the result like the edit in my answer im now adding?